# chrome extension: run observer on DOM change

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

In my browser extension, I would like to run some code every time the DOM content has changed. I've tried putting this

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
    console.log(`${mutation.type} has been changed.`);
  }
});
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(document.body, config);
```

into the `content_script`, but the observer never triggers.

Any hints?

Comment: Your config is missing `subtree: true`

Comment: @wOxxOm If you promote this to an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.